# Android view layout design help

Tags: android, android-layout

Last week i started to develop an android app and almost done the coding part but the layout design for the app is too confusing...
The following is the design what i wanted,
[image]

Anyone please give me the coding part to create the design/layout. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look on the code. It wil produce the result exactly same as you want.
Donot forget to vote the answer.

have a look [here also](http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/01/android/android-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#ffffff">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/a_thumb" />
    <LinearLayout


        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="name"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip" />
        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="data"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="Time-Like-Comment"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: Wc. Thanks for your acceptance. I am really happy that I am able to resolve your problem upto some extent. for further problems you can contact me.

Comment: and a doubt, when i put two status feeds the second feed goes hidden in right hand side. I need it to be downside of first feed. Can you give layout for at-least two status feeds please???...

Comment: can you ellaborate or send the the screen shot of the result that you are expecting

Answer (score 2):

This may be helpful - http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html.

Also read about ListView (http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should check , creating custom listview , and all the things you require can easily be achieved.

Check here,
http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/